# Как в phpstorm подключить папку вне проекта

Tags: php, phpstorm

Хочу подключить папку к проекту и работать в ней но она лежит вне папки проекта, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте настройки (ctrl + alt + s), зайдите в раздел `Directories` и справа добавьте новый `content root`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого в дереве каталогов проекта появится новая папка.

Answer (score 2):

Заходим с `Settings->Directories`. Там будет `+Add Content Root`. Добавляем папку и наслаждаемся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]